# i want "enter data" msg when ever i click on submit button without filling the details and decreasing id value whenever i delete 1 item

Tags: android

i have created a app with 3 edit text and and 3 buttons,

Edittext:
- id
- name
- date

Button:

- submit.
- check.
- delete.
- name to store name of user,
- date to store date,
- submit to store data in sqlit database,
- check to retrive data,
- delete to delete the specfied id in database,
- id is auto incremented it is used when deleting.

my problem here is if i not enter anything in the edit text it takes null values
and display as shown in below pic instead of taking null i want to show message "PLEASE ENTER DATA"
and whenever i delete data  next id value must decrease by 1 please help me. 
[image: image of output what is get]

Answer (score 0):

```
Before entering the data to database use should check EditTexts are null or not  in on click method and if null print toast messages like below



    idEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
    nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
    dateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Date);

    String id = idEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String name = nameEditText.getText().toString().();
    String date = dateEditText.getText().toString().();

    if(id.length() == 0 || name.length() == 0 || date.length())
    {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 idEditText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
nameEditText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
dateEditText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Date);

private boolean checkEmptyFields() {
    boolean check = false
    String id = idEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String name = nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String date = dateEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (id.isEmpty()) {
        idEditText.setError("Invalid Input");
        check = true;
    } else {
        dEditText.setError(null);
        check = false;
    }

    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        nameEditText.setError("Invalid Input");
        check = true;
    } else {
        nameEditText.setError(null);
        check = false;
    }

    if (date.isEmpty()) {
        dateEditText.setError("Invalid Input");
        check = true;
    } else {
        dateEditText.setError(null);
        check = false;
    }
 return check;
}



if (!checkEmptyFields())
{
//Add Data to DB
}
```